# Docker build is different between docker desktop and Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I have a simple dockerfile which I am trying to inject vc_redist into the container, when I build the image using docker desktop my appliaction runs correctly, however when I build the same image in Azure Pipeline and than pull that image from Azure Container Registry I am missing the vc_redist layers. Why is there a difference between building the image using docker desktop and Azure Pipeline Tasks? Here is a sample of my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS base
WORKDIR /app

USER ContainerAdministrator
ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9fbed7c7-7012-4cc0-a0a3-a541f51981b5/e7eec15278b4473e26d7e32cef53a34c/vc_redist.x64.exe /vc_redist.x64.exe 
RUN /vc_redist.x64.exe /norestart /install /quiet
RUN del /vc_redist.x64.exe

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet restore .....
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build ....

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ...

FROM base AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["myapp.exe"]
```

Comment: Are you using windows or linux agents? Are you sure all

Comment: windows container

Comment: but your devops agents, are they also windows?

Answer (score 0):

your URL is not working here. (it's probably a private URL only for your IP or time based)

see https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/issues/15

he uses a Microsoft download link that is working

`https://download.microsoft.com`
while you use a visual studio link `https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/`

I would suggest to download the installer and re-upload it to a gist or GitHub, or just add the file itself to the docker

Comment: The link to vc_redist is fine, copy it into any browser and it downloads, furthermore like I posted, it builds and runs just fine when built using docker desktop. the issue is when using docker pipeline task is when vc_redist is being dropped from the final container